# Conneting to Azure Remote App via HTML 5 client

Tags: html, azure, remote-access, gateway

Currently I'm investigating the possibility's to connect to Azure Remote Apps using an HTML 5 client.

But for now I can't find a way to connect to the Azure server which is hosting the remote apps.

I have the following question regarding Azure Remote Apps.
Is it possible to connect to Azure remote apps using 3rth party sofware like guacamole? Or are Azure Remote Apps completely locked from external connections?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I a use remotespark sometimes to connect to my Azure VM's. It doesn't need any installation either...

http://www.remotespark.com/view/rdp.html

Answer (score 0):

If Azure Remote Apps use the RDP protocol, I think it's possible. I know that RemoteSpark use an HTTP to RDP gateway, like [Guacamole](https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client), so it should work.

I open sourced recently a very comparable solution, [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille), more intended for Windows Servers as it's coded in .NET (C#) and hosted on IIS, I'll have a look if it works too with Azure (not tested).